# Click on OK button in webbrowser

Tags: vb.net

I'm using gecko `webbrowser` in vb.net to navigate to one page.

Problem is when i open that page i still need to ok

[image: Can't post images . Go through link]

I thought to go with `invoke member`. `GetElemnetById` but i don't know id od this button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as easy as you'd think, this is where [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/index.aspx) comes to the rescue.

Below code was taken from [this discussion](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?682937-How-to-auto-choose-OK-if-Webbrowser-shows-up-confirm-message) and provided here in case link becomes obsolete:

```
' test code, click OK button on dialog window...
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint:="FindWindow")> _
    Private Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lclassName As String, ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SendMessage")> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(hwnd As IntPtr, wMsg As Integer, wParam As Integer, lParam As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function
    Private Const BM_CLICK As Integer = &HF5
    Private Const WM_ACTIVATE As Integer = &H6
    Private Const WA_ACTIVE As Integer = 1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' find dialog window with titlebar text of "Message from webpage"
        Dim hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "Message from webpage")
        If hwnd <> IntPtr.Zero Then ' dialog window found
            ' find button on dialog window: classname = "Button", text = "OK"
            Dim btn = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK")
            If btn <> IntPtr.Zero Then ' button found
                ' activate the button on dialog first or it may not acknowledge a click msg on first try
                SendMessage(btn, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_ACTIVE, 0)
                ' send button a click message
                SendMessage(btn, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
            Else
                MsgBox("button not found!")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("window not found!")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

You should be able to use a Timer to trigger the button click. If you prefer not to have a button on UI, just put this code into a custom sub, and call that inside your Timer.

Credit goes to @Edgemeal, member of [VB Forums](http://www.vbforums.com).